# How to Bind to a Custom Controls Button Visibility from Within Another Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a custom control, which has a button:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gambit.Views.FileSelectionControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    ...
    <Button Content="Load" 
            Margin="5,5,5,5" 
            Height="22" 
            Width="70" 
            IsDefault="True" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedFileExists}" 
            AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="Click" 
            AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}"/>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

I want to include this control, in another control, but I want to set the `Load` buttons visibility at design time in the host control; something like

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gambit.Views.SomeOtherControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    ...
    <GroupBox Header="Select Test Data">
        <Views:FileSelectionControl <Here Set the Load Button Visibility>/>
    </GroupBox>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

where `<Here Set the Load Button Visibility>` shows where i want to set the visibility of the control. How is this done [without breaking the MVVM pattern]?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can create `DependencyProperty` within your `UserControl` and internally bind it to `Button` visibility

Comment: Whats the condition on which basis you want to set the Visibility of button

Comment: Basically I want to be able to embed this control and the ascociated ViewModel in a window (include the buttons) or a control (exclude the buttons). This can be set at design time. If this was to be done at run-time I would have a chance as i have done this before - however, I have never set the visibility of one component of a control from another...

Comment: @dkozl can you provide a small example of this. I don't understand how to create a dp 'within' a `UserControl`? Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `DependencyProperty` in your `UserControl`:

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{
    ...

    public static DependencyProperty ButtonVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(SomeView));

    public Visibility ButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

bind it to `Button.Visibility`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.SomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ButtonVisibility}" Content="My Button"/>
</UserControl>
```

and then you can control `Visibility` from outside like so:

```
<local:SomeView ButtonVisibility="Collapsed"/>
```

and because it's a `DependencyProperty` you can use `Binding` as well

Comment: Does this have to be in the controls code behind? I am trying to keep strictly nothing in the code-behind. Thanks very much for your time...

Comment: You don't manipulate views in code. It's just another `DependencyProperty`, like `UserControl.Visibility`, via which you control visibility of a `Button` within. Everything is still controlled from your ViewModel so you don't break MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Hi just create a bool or Visibility Type property in UserControl1 and set it in Usercontrol2 like

> UserControl1 xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Loadbutton" Content="load"/>
</Grid>
```

> xaml.cs

```
 public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool showLoadButton;
    public bool ShowLoadButton
    {
        get { return showLoadButton; }
        set
        {
            showLoadButton = value;
            if (showLoadButton)
                Loadbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                Loadbutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

> UserControl2 Set ShowLoadButton True or false

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 ShowLoadButton="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time here... However, this breaks the MVVM pattern as it couples the view to its code-behind...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to define a property in the `UserControl`, which you can always create *attached* dependency property, and you can declare it in a separate class under the common namespace.

Something like this:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<local:TestUserControl AttachedProperties:ButtonExt.Visibility="Visible" />
```

`TestUserControl.xaml`

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                             Path=(AttachedProperties:ButtonExt.Visibility)}"
        Content="TestButton" />
```

Attached property definition:

```
public static class ButtonExt
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty;

    public static void SetVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject, Visibility value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    public static Visibility GetVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Visibility)DepObject.GetValue(VisibilityProperty);
    }

    static ButtonExt()
    {
        PropertyMetadata VisibiltyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed);

        VisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Visibility",
                                                            typeof(Visibility),
                                                            typeof(ButtonExt),
                                                            VisibiltyPropertyMetadata);
    }
}
```

**`Some notes about code-behind in MVVM`**

I agree with @dkozl, his example does not violate the principle of MVVM, in some cases, the code is present in the `View`, for example (personally, I always try to avoid code-behind):

- Installation `DataContext`.
- The use of different patterns such as Mediator, Proxy, etc.
- Determination of properties and behaviors that pertain only to `View` (as in your case).

The most important thing when you use the code-behind, it is that all actions possible through `ViewModel` occurred, ie in `ViewModel` contains all the logic and for example, in the `View` click event, call the function, which is in `ViewModel`.

For more information about code-behind, please see the answers to the recent question:

[WPF MVVM Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883199/wpf-mvvm-code-behind)