# SelectOnEntry for wpf textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to select all text into a textbox just when it got focus , there is a property named SelectOnEntry in wpf texbox or an equivalent?

If Not how to implment it ?

Comment: If you want to do it with a "behaviour" (by way of an attached property) instead of code-behind, then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808974/initial-focus-and-select-all-behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically select all text on focus in WPF TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660554/how-to-automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach handler for `GotFocus` event:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
```

and in handler:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

---

If you need to do it in pure XAML way, you can **create an attached property to select all text on focus**. Refer to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810516/632337).

Comment: There is no native option for this ?

Comment: Native option doesn't exist. However, if you want XAML approach, you can create attached property like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7810516/632337).